Running sum in the same cell
I need to compare a value with the sum of an expanding range.
I have this formula here:
=CHOOSE({1,2,3},SUM(D4),SUM(D4:D5),SUM(D4:D6))
Wondering if there is a way to get an array of sums in the same cell without writing out every sum with its own range but make it more compact. I've tried INDIRECT("D4:D"&{4,5,6}) but it would only return the first value.
Thanks.

Could you explain a bit further please?  At the moment you're showing a formula without explaining how the data is expanding.  Maybe =SUM(D$4:D4) and drag down?  Or maybe =SUM(D4:INDEX($D:$D,COUNTA($D:$D))+3) or maybe just put the data within a table and then =SUM(Table1[Column1])

If you have Office 365 SCAN does exactly that: =SCAN(,D4:D6,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))

Or for beta insiders: =SCAN(,D4:D6,SUM)

@ Darren Bartrup-Cook If you enter the formula and hit F9 you'll see what's required, and I didn't want to use any helper columns.

Or make it a table: =SUM(INDEX([Column1],1):[@Column1])

Using @P.b SCAN technique try =TRANSPOSE(SCAN(,D4:INDEX($D:$D,COUNTA($D:$D)+3),LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))) - sorry, put the +3 in the wrong place on my original comment.

@DarrenBartrup-Cook Transposed =SCAN(,TOROW(D4:D99,1),LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))

Thanks for apparently great solutions; the pity is I don't have Office 365 to try these.

So you tried the table solution (ctrl+T on you range)

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhxknrNHLDPCgZdIuh2D1CdpwYnv8g

@ P.b Yes, and it gave me the total sum instead of a range of sums.

Is this what you're trying to get (required Microsoft 365):
=LET(
    d, D4:D6,
    running_sum, LAMBDA(r,
        ARRAYTOTEXT(MAP(SEQUENCE(r), LAMBDA(i, SUM(TAKE(d, i)))))
    ),
    MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)), running_sum)
)


